# Changing colors in blocks

Tags: javascript, html, css

There are 4 blocks. I need to get each of them in turn changed the background color to red. On the second lap I get an error. How to fix?

```js
var spanElems = [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('.block__item') ),
    i = 0, timer, prev;

(function foo() {
  spanElems[prev || 0].style.background = '';

  prev = i;
  spanElems[i++ % spanElems.length].style.background = 'red';
  console.log(i, prev);
  timer = setTimeout(foo, 3000);
})();
```

```css
.block {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.block__item {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <span class="block__item">1</span>
  <span class="block__item">2</span>
  <span class="block__item">3</span>
  <span class="block__item">4</span>
</div>
```

Sandbox: http://jsbin.com/lowimewegu/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `prev` ends up greater than spanElems.length, so spanElems[prev] is undefined. Try:
`prev = i % spanElems.length;` in place of `prev = i;`

Comment: No problem! Good luck with the rest of your coding.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error indicates that you can't get the style property of null and it doesn't appear that the `prev` variable ever gets reset back to 0 after reaching 4, so it would seem that `prev` is the issue.